# TSQL - For Each like Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to do a SQL For Each -like statement and I can't get my head around it.

If my **TABLE_A** Looks like this:

```
[dbo].[TABLE_A](
    [EmpID] [INT],
    [FName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LName] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

...and my **TABLE_B** looks like this:

```
[dbo].[TABLE_B](
    [EmployeeActivity] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmpID] [INT]
)
```

Can someone help me write a query to do something like this:

```
FOR EACH DISTINCT [EmployeeActivity] RETURN 
  [TABLE_B].[EmployeeActivity],
  [TABLE_A].[FName], 
  [TABLE_A].[LName], 
  [TABLE_A].[EmpID],
  CASE
    WHEN ([TABLE_B].[EmployeeActivity] IS NULL) THEN ('NO')
  ELSE 'YES'
  END
```

Results should look like:

```
FireDrill12, Bill, Jones, 342,YES
FireDrill13, Bill, Jones, 342,NO
FireDrill14, Bill, Jones, 342,YES
FireDrill12, Smith, Sue, 253,NO
FireDrill13, Smith, Sue, 253,NO
FireDrill14, Smith, Sue, 253,YES
```

I can't get my head around this.

Thanks for any help,

-Allen

Comment: Your FOR EACH... statement is not a proper specification of what you want. The results example table looks like you need a simple JOIN!?

Comment: And the example data doesn't make sense.  The EmployeeActivity in the first column is never null, so you won't see NO in the last column.  To expand on the previous comment, you'll want a SELECT statement with an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another version using `inner` join but the more correct version using `left` join is as shown by @Blam

```
SELECT 
    A.*, 
    CASE
        WHEN B.EmployeeActivity IS NULL THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END
FROM
[dbo].[TABLE_A] A
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TABLE_B] B ON (A.EmpID = B.EmpID)
UNION
SELECT 
    A.*, 
    'No'
FROM
[dbo].[TABLE_A] A
WHERE 
A.EmpID NOT IN (SELECT B.EmpID FROM [dbo].[TABLE_B] B)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       [TABLE_A].[EmpID], [TABLE_A].[FName], [TABLE_A].[LName] 
     , CASE
          WHEN [TABLE_B].[EmployeeActivity] IS NULL THEN 'No'
          ELSE 'Yes'
       END AS [EmployeeActivity]
  FROM [TABLE_A]
  LEFT JOIN [TABLE_B] 
    ON [TABLE_B].[EmpID] = [TABLE_A].[EmpID]
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a set based language anyway, so it is already doing your "for each", so in theory you could do a CROSS JOIN to get every combination, with a correlated query to do your check, so maybe something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            b.EmployeeActivity,
            a.FName,
            a.LName,
            a.EmpId,
            CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [TABLE_B] c WHERE c.[EmployeeActivity] = b.EmployeeActivity AND c.EmpId = a.EmpId) THEN 'YES' 
                ELSE 'NO' 
            END

FROM        Table_b AS b

CROSS JOIN  Table_a AS a
    ON      a.EmpId = b.EmpId
```